# get the first few items order by item's count

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

```
source array:
a1 = [1,2,2,2,3,4,]
a2 = [3,5,6,7,8,8,]
a3 = [3,4,7,8,9,9,]
a4 = [2,3,5,7,8,9,]

number     count
  1          1
  2          4
  3          4
  4          2
  5          2
  6          1
  7          3
  8          4
  9          3
```

I want to get the first 4 number order by count. And return in type of list. The result will be `[2,3,8,7]` or `[2,3,8,9]`.

I tried to use array function in Python. But find it has no efficiency. So I found numpy. But I am not familiar with numpy. Can anyone get the result by numpy? Or is there an other more efficient way?

Comment: Why do I feel like this question has been asekd at least half a dozen times in the last couple of days with identical answers every time! Use the ``Counter`` class :)

Comment: Sorry, you can only mark *one* answer as accepted. Glad you found both to be helpful, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy option which will only be faster for very large arrays:

```
complete = np.concatenate((a1,a2,a3,a4))
uvals, uind = np.unique(complete, return_inverse=True)
uvals[np.bincount(uind).argsort()[-4:]][::-1]

array([8, 3, 2, 9])
```

If you must have a list you can use the `tolist()` option:

```
uvals[np.bincount(uind).argsort()[-4:]][::-1].tolist()

[8, 3, 2, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(a1)
for lst in (a2, a3, a4):
    counts.update(lst)

for number, count in counts.most_common(4):
    print number, count
```

The `Counter.most_common()` method gives you the entries in sorted order; here we asked for the 4 most common entries.

If you want do have just a list of the 4 numbers, use:

```
top4 = [n for n, c in counts.most_common(4)]
```

You could also just concatenate the input lists, but it'd be best if you used `itertools.chain` for that:

```
from collection import Counter
from itertools import chain

counts = Counter(chain(a1, a2, a3, a4))
```

and not create a full list object you'll only discard again.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a1 = [1,2,2,2,3,4,]
>>> a2 = [3,5,6,7,8,8,]
>>> a3 = [3,4,7,8,9,9,]
>>> a4 = [2,3,5,7,8,9,]
>>> counts = Counter(a1)
>>> for lst in (a2, a3, a4):
...     counts.update(lst)
... 
>>> for number, count in counts.most_common(4):
...     print number, count
... 
2 4
3 4
8 4
7 3
>>> [n for n, c in counts.most_common(4)]
[2, 3, 8, 7]
```